# Is it possible in SQL Server to change default "order by" direction from asc to desc?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This question came up in a discussion at work... given the following T-SQL statement:

```
select firstname, lastname from users order by lastname;
```

the default sort order on the `order by` clause is `asc`.

Is there a setting within SQL Server that will allow you to change the default order used when the `ASC|DESC` modifiers are not specified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the default sort order is always ASC.

Comment: which is required by the SQL standard if I'm not mistaken (but that wouldn't bother Microsoft on the other hand...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think 5-10 years ago that would have been a fair statement, but they've been much better in recent versions at actually paying attention to the standards. They've at least stopped violating them, and I welcome extensions they add over and above what the standard defines.